# Anyone know when gwt apis will support google maps v3

Tags: google-maps, gwt, google-maps-api-3

Basically what the title says - i've looked around, and on the gwt-maps page it has said for a long time "as of the gwt-maps-1.1 release, the current bindings are only compatible with the Maps v2 APIs"

There's the "gwt-google-maps-v3" project, but the header there has said for almost a year "This project will soon be merged into gwt-google-apis and hence is depricated"

I've looked around but not found anything more than that - does anyone know what Google's plans are here?

Comment: Perhaps asking the people working on those projects would be a better idea?

Comment: Uhm thanks for downranking... The reason i posted here is because stackoverflow usually is Google's go-to place for asking questions. I've been sitting with Android for the last months and this is their recommended community (at least they say so on their main page). Sorry if i made a mistake, i'll look for another place now.

Comment: @Mathias +1 for posting here. Google's teams are notorious for both never responding to their own forums and for making promises to "soon" add a feature/API and never follow up. Thus, posting on SO is the clear and obvious solution.

Comment: Thanks, couldn't agree more. I guess Brian had a bad day...

Comment: This has been the most sought after feature of GWT for at least the last couple of years. The only progress they have made is to put v2 in the deprecated list. Pitiful.

Comment: Yeah, kinda sad. Feels like GWT is kinda slow on the adding of features in general..

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want. Although the documentation SUCKS on the -v3 project, if you dig into the source you'll see that many of the Maps object types are supported. I implemented my own solution via JSNI before doing said digging into the source.

Here's an example of my own JSNI solution:

https://github.com/dartmanx/mapmaker/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jason/mapmaker/client/util/GoogleMapUtil.java

The advantages of JSNI are that you don't have to worry about the lack of support of the -v3 project.